# how to push a viewController with flip animation

Tags: pushviewcontroller

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
alarmViewController = [[AlarmViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:alarmViewController animated:YES];
[alarmViewController release];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I just want the viewcontroller flip like opening a book page,but it does not work like this.And I have a question that whether navigationController can animate this effect?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already putting the `navigationController` in an animation block. Mark `animated:NO` -

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:alarmViewController animated:NO];`

when we actually call `pushViewController:` we are setting the animated value to NO. This disables the Navigation Controller's default animation. Instead, the block of code uses the defined transition.